# upgrade nativescript app to api level 26+

Tags: android, nativescript

Is possible get to upgrade my nativescript app to api level 26, I am looking for, but I have not found anything.

The date limit is on October.

Or I must to create a new app since beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the `minSdkVersion` or the `targetSdkVersion`? Both can be found in the `App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`. You can also use the following command: `tns build android --compileSdk 26`, but that is obviously not permanent.

I think in your case changing the `minSdkVersion` should be fine.

Comment: thanks, your help is appreciated, but at the end I had updated my app as docs say, then my targetSdkVersion changed, so I have readied my app.